# How would my work computer know all my home computer's wifi passwords?

Tags: wifi, password, keychain

I just started a new job and brought the work MBP home to do some work remotely, and the second I opened it up, it connected to my home wifi.  How could it know that already?  I looked at my Keychain Access app, and it seems to have all my "AirPort network passwords" from more than the past decade on it.  Every single wifi I've connected to since like 2010.

The best I can remember, the only time I typed in my personal password on it was to grab a free app from the App Store.  Would doing that also somehow sync my wifi passwords?

Might there have been something else I have done that I'm just not remembering that would do this?  Looking through Keychain Access, I'm not seeing any of my personal website login passwords saved or anything.  The surprises seem limited to the wifi passwords.

Comment: Did you sign into your personal iCloud on your work Mac?

Comment: When you look at your Apple ID under System Preferences, does your work MBP appear in the list of devices?

Comment: Is your phone synched to your work Mac? if so, trusted devices share passwords. I went to a friend's house with my new mac which had never been there and it connected.

Comment: So this is interesting... I believe the only time I entered in my Apple ID/password on the computer was when I downloaded an app from the app store.  Though when I go to System Settings, I do see it has my account under Apple ID.  And the work does indeed show up under my list of computers (though on my work computer under devices it just says "Failed to load devices").

Comment: Is iCloud Keychain enabled on both devices? This is the mechanism which shares WiFi SSIDs and the passwords associated with them.